# If we have a function f:N->S, where we know f is onto, is S countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working on this homework problem in my discrete mathematics class and I just wanted some feedback on my proof/logic.

I say that, no, this set S is not countable because we know that the definition of countability is that there needs to be a bijection established where f:N->S (or S->N) or that the set we wish to count is finite.

In this case our function f only establishes an onto relationship which is no guarantee that our set S is countable. We don't have any information on whether or not the set S is finite.

Am I possibly missing something in my logic or is my reasoning sound?

Comment: Sometimes the definition of "countable" includes finite sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila right, and when the set is infinite in order for it to be deemed as countable there has to be a bijection established between the set and the set of all natural numbers, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you can conclude is that $S$ is countable **or finite**. But the latter case is certainly possible: take e.g. $S=\{17\}$ and $f:x\mapsto 17$.

Of course, as Asaf Karagila said, many (most?) texts define "countable" to permit finite sets. Under such a definition (usually: "$X$ is countable iff there is an injection $X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$"), countability is equivalent to the existence of a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$.